# Array of array of parameters with more than 1000 records in node express and Kraken

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, node.js, express

I am having a json object and want to post them to the kraken server. I am using ajax to post the data and it works for parameter of less than 1K records but the same is not working beyond certain limit.

```
$.ajax({ url: '', method: 'GET', dataType:'json', data: {prop1:'ABC',prop2:method()} });
function method(){ var arr = []; arr[0]=[]; arr[0][0]=1; arr[0][1]=2... till 2000; return arr;}
```

The request is intercepted by the middle and giving 500 error with lot of %5D etc characters.

Comment: Did you try request with multipart data?

Answer (score 0):

It is resolved after adding contentType:"application/json" and data: JSON.stringify()